# How do you read input file from a USB thumb drive in java?

Tags: java, file-io, usb-drive

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("INPUT.txt"));
```

This is what I have so far and I keep getting a `java.io.FileNotFoundException`.
Is there a way to find the file. Here are the directions I have been given, "The instructor will provide your group with a USB thumb drive in the root directory of which resides a text file named INPUT.TXT"

Comment: Are you running this program in the root directory of the USB drive?

Comment: no, how do I do that?

Comment: You don't have to. But if you're not, you'll have to use the full file path. Otherwise it's relative to the current directly.

Comment: is there a way to locate the file anywhere on my system

Comment: Do you not know how file paths work? Come on, this is extremely basic stuff. It's not even programming-related.

Comment: so in the path if I put the USB drive path, it will grab the file from there essentially?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169379/discussion-between-yoobi-and-shmosel).

Answer (score 0):

use
`Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("E:\\INPUT.txt")`

Right now its trying to find input.txt in the local directory, which is where the java project is.

You might not have it as the E drive, so make sure the drive letter is correct.

to use backslashes in java Strings you need two: \ - one to escape the other, as \ is used to escape characters sure as \n and \t